# React redux - Passing store from a function <Provider store={configureStore()}> creates a new store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having a hard time with something and I'm not sure this is expected behaviour.

I have created a container wrapper that takes the connected component as an argument:

```
import store from 'somewhere'

const ComponentWrapper = (Container, railsProps, _railsContext) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}> 
      <Container {...railsProps} />
    </Provider>
  )
};
```

with store.js defined as such:

```
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic, {
    dependencies: {}
  });

  const logger = createLogger({
    collapsed: true,
  });

export default createStore(RootReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware, logger))
```

Happy days, as expected only one store is created, each component is connected to that one store. I will end up inserting more than one of these components in to a page and despite each component being wrapped in it's own provider/store, redux knows to only use one store. The behaviour here is exactly what I want and expect.

However, if I redefine my store.js:

```
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic, {
    dependencies: {}
  });

  const logger = createLogger({
    collapsed: true,
  });

export const configureStore = (railsState) => {
    return createStore(RootReducer, railsState, applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware, logger))
}
```

export default configureStore
and wrap my component just as above but with the change

```
<Provider store={configureStore({})}> 
      <Container {...railsProps} />
</Provider>
```

When mounting the components I have that each component has it's own store. I believe it might have something to do with setting of storeKey? However, I believe this is unexpected behaviour since `configureStore({}) returns createStore(RootReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware, logger))` exactly like before.

Why do I believe each component have their own stores? Because if I define my store as initially, and I mount two copies of the same component in to my DOM, each component listens to the same change in state (via dispatching actions) and rerenders accordingly - as expected - these two components have been connected to the same slice of state, the change of which causes the rerender in BOTH components - makes me smile every time. If I define store.js as shown in the latter definition, a change of one component only shows in that component and not in the other meaning that the two components are listening to two different slices of state. Since they are just a copy of the exact same component (technically container since I am using the container/presentation component pattern) they are both in fact connected to different stores.

I hope I have explained this correctly.

Comment: it is the expected behaviour. May be you are confused with the way export default works. Object exported by a .js file will be calculated only once during the inital import and thereafter cached.

Comment: Thank you. That makes complete sense.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting official [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles):

> **Single source of truth**
>
> The state of your whole application is stored in an object tree within
>   a single store.

I am not sure if you really need to wrap your components with other stores. At least for the most use cases you don't need to do that and you will be having hard time sharing data between those stores.

Instead of creating store this way:

```
<Provider store={configureStore({})}> 
      <Container {...railsProps} />
</Provider>
```

Invoke creation of your store on import

```
const store = configureStore()

// Just one Provider on top level, 
// you can wrap <Provider> with react router v4 <Router>
// App is our root component
<Provider store={store}> 
      <App />
</Provider>
```

See redux examples https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response. It is important to note that if I wrap each Container in a store I get ONE store for the entire app. I only get one store if I define the provider (around EACH component) as such `<Provider store={store}>`. However if I define the provider like this `<Provider store={configureStore({})}>` I get each component with their own stores. The usefulness of this pattern can be seen when you have a serverside app. What you are describing is a SPA with a root component. We are using this pattern because we have a rails app in the backend that deals with our routing